# Data 'location' must be "storage" or "memory" but none were given?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am in a course on udemy and I copied the code on the screen and am getting an error for my location string.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity 0.8.1;

contract PropertyV2 {
    uint public value;
    string public location;
    //address public owner;

constructor(uint _value, string _location) public {
    value = _value;
    location = _location;
}

function setValue(uint _value) public {
    value = _value;
}

function getLocation() public view returns(string) {
    return location;
}}
```

I know this doesn't haven't much context. He was just explaining the basics of the code and contract name, compiler version, constructor, etc. But when I typed in the code it was giving an error just wanted to know how to fix the error to give the location string memory. I thought I was assigning it memory or storage in the constructor?

Comment: Your constructor should be declared this way : 
`constructor(uint _value, string memory _location) public {`
Read this chapter from the [solidity documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.3/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html?highlight=storage#storage-memory-and-the-stack) for details about storage and memory.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am reading the material you provided